# does anyone know what to do in this error? its for my self teach programming skills\

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

this is the syntax i put in my code but i dunno whats should replace here
`Run4Start = datetime.datetime.strptime(CurrentDate, '%H:%M %y/%m/%d')`
and this the error that the output gave me   **TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime**

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M %y/%m/%d')`. Note that `date`, `datetime`, and `time` objects all support a `strftime(format)` method. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to **parse** datetime from string:

```
your_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_to_parse_from, pattern)

# example
my_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime("08:00 20/01/17", '%H:%M %y/%m/%d')
print(my_datetime) # datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 17, 8, 0)
```

If you want to **format** a datetime to pattern:

```
your_formatted_string = datetime.datetime.strftime(date_to_format, pattern)

# example
datetime_now = datetime.datetime.now()
my_formatted_datetime = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime_now, '%H:%M %y/%m/%d')
print(my_datetime) # 08:00 20/01/17
```

You can read more about it here: [datetime strptime/strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

In addition you can call strftime on the datetime object itself:

```
your_formatted_string = date_to_format.strftime(pattern)
```